# What versions of Minecraft are available for Windows 10, and what are their differences?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm wondering about versions of Minecraft. We have it on Android and have decided to buy it for our laptop. It's a Lenovo Laptop and uses Windows 10.

There is a Starter Collection and a Master Collection. There are also PE, Java, Bedrock Edition, Redstone Edition, and several other types of Minecraft. Are any of these versions difficult to play on a laptop? What are the differences between them?

Comment: It seems you're asking multiple questions at once. It would be better if you could ask those questions separately, like: "What is the difference between Minecraft PE, Minecraft Java, and all the other types of Minecraft?" At present, I'm seeing 3 different questions in this one. Also, try to be specific, for example: "*there is a starter edition and and the master edition*" Is this about the Lenovo Laptop, Windows 10, or Minecraft? And what do you mean by "difficult to play?" Are you talking about the game's controls, or about game installation/setup?

Comment: And since you're new, make sure you do not respond to those comments using the big "Your Answer" textbox below. Click on "Add a comment" instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 versions of minecraft, Bedrock and Java. They each have pros and cons. Bedrock edition is the same version you have on your mobile device, so I don't need to tell you about that, the differences are minimal between platforms, however java is very different from bedrock. There are some key differences I will list.

- You **cannot** play java servers with bedrock edition and **cannot** play bedrock servers with java edition. However some servers are both bedrock and java however a bedrock player and java player still **cant play together**.
- Java edition has the ability to play **any version of minecraft** ever released, bedrock can only play the latest
- Bedrock and java have two **very different combat systems**.
- Java edition has **more customizability** due to the fact that it is much easier to mod the game.
- Java edition has **no marketplace**, meaning almost all maps, resource packs and other downloadable community made content is **free**
- Skins dont cost money on Java edition
- There are **no emotes** with java edition (though you can install mods to add them)
- there is **no skin creator** in java edition
- There is a debug menu that shows details about the game like your coordinates in java edition
- Java edition and bedrock edition have different command structures for some commands and bedrock edition has much less support for nbt changing commands
- Java edition is by default **less optimized**, however many mods like sodium and optifine **optimize it very well**

That's pretty much all I could think of, feel free to edit this if I got something wrong.

Comment: at this point, everything is very helpful to me. when i go to the microsoft store and download minecraft.......do i just input 'minecraft' in the search box? or is there another version? idk im so sorry im new to all of this. and thank you very much. that helped me so much1

Comment: The microsoft store only has bedrock edition (called [windows 10 edition](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/minecraft-for-windows-10-starter-collection/9n4km90ctzt6?=&rtc=2&activetab=pivot:regionofcompareeditionstab)), if you want java edition you have to go to the [minecraft website](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/store/minecraft-java-edition). There is also minecraft dungeons, however that is a different game. The difference between starter and master for bedrock is you get some minecoins included to use in the marketplace.

Comment: which do you recommend java or bedrock?

Comment: I personally would recommend java edition, however if you mainly want to **play with others** i would recommend **bedrock edition**, as consoles and mobile are all bedrock edition, but only pc is java edition. And if you have really only played bedrock the move to java edition could be pretty hard since many things are different. If neither of those bother you too much i would go for java.

Comment: @VickiPhillips, I would recommend the Windows 10 Edition for 2 reasons: 1. you seem concerned about ease-of-use. The Java version requires you to install Java in addition to Minecraft, and requires a minimum of computer literacy. The Bedrock version doesn't; you're only required to click a button to purchase and install the game. 2. You're playing on a laptop, and your "computer illiteracy", as you put it, suggests that your laptop might not be very powerful. Minecraft Java is significantly more resource-hungry than Bedrock, so the Windows 10 Edition is likely better suited to you.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to Topcode's answer, the *Starter Collection* and *Master Collection* are not actually separate editions of Minecraft; they are bundles that include a bunch of optional add-ons, together with *Minecraft for Windows 10* (which is the Bedrock Edition of the game).

It's probably best to purchase just the game by itself, unless you know for sure you want those specific add-ons. You can always purchase add-ons later.